# First letter is changed into @ in copied string

Tags: c

Here is the code for copying string in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    int i;
    printf("Enter string s1:");
    fgets(s1,sizeof(s1),stdin);

    for(i=1;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        s2[i]=s1[i];
    }
    s2[i]='\0';
    printf("%s",s2);
}
```

However, when I enter **"How are you?"**, the copied string become **"@ow are you?"**

Comment: C arrays start at 0, not 1.

Comment: There is a function called `strncpy` that can do this for you, instead of writing your own loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays start at 0, your `for` loop should look like this

```c
for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++) {
   // ^ 0, not 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The for-loop must start at the index 0. So change your for loop to this:

```
for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    s2[i]=s1[i];
}
```